# MS Word footer and chapter numbering issues

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers, footers

I hope someone can help. I am editing a book that a colleague formatted (he has since retired). The first section is numbered in roman numerals. All is well until the beginning of Chapter 1. In the footer we use a hyphenated system Chapter 1, page 1 would be 1-1. 
For some reason, My chapter 1 starts with 2-1. The rest of the book (9 more chapters and an appendix) is numbered correctly. When I format page numbers in the header and footer tools, nothing changes. As far a I can tell the footers are identical! Any ideas?
John

Comment: Check the fields for section numbering, make sure they are updated, compare them with those of correctly numbered sections. Hard to be more specific without more details

Answer (score 1):

John, this is actually pretty simple to fix.  First, verify that your footer for Chapter 1 is not linked to the footer for the front matter.  From the Tell Me box, enter Edit Footer.  This will open the footer in your document.  Advance to the Chapter 1 section.  On the Header/Footer Design menu, verify that "Link to Previous" is not selected (callout 1). 
[image: Ensure Link to Previous is not selected]

Once you've verified that your footer isn't linked to the previous section footer, select the "Insert" ribbon, then select the small arrow to the right of "Page Number" (callout 2). This will open the Format Page Numbers dialog box (callout 3). 
[image: Opening Format Page Numbers menu]

Next, you'll want to select the number format (1, 2, 3 ...) (callout 4); select "Include chapter number" (callout 5); and select the correct format for page numbering ("Start at 1") (callout 6).
[image: Steps 4, 5, and 6]

Select "OK."  If you don't have a list style applied to your Section 1 heading, you will get a warning.  In this case, apply the appropriate list style to your Heading 1 style.  If you need help with List Styles, please create a new question.

Good luck and respond back to let me know if this solves your problem.